# How to layout wxPython panels that expand both directions

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm building a UI in wxPython,<sup>[note 1]</sup> and I have three main body panels, two toolbars, and a status bar, with two `BoxSizer` elements (a vertical one containing all of the above, and a horizontal one containing the body panels). I cannot get the layout to work quite right, and I'm getting some behavior that I can't find in the documentation. I'm leaving out some details, but here is the relevant (working) part of the app:

```
import wx
import wx.adv

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = AppFrame(parent=None, title="My Sweet App")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

class AppFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, size=(1024, 768), *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(size=size, *args, **kwargs)

        # Menu (quit only)
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu = wx.Menu()

        quit_item = wx.MenuItem(
            file_menu, wx.ID_EXIT, '&Exit', 'Close the application')
        file_menu.Append(quit_item)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnQuit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)
        menubar.Append(file_menu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        # Outer box wrapper
        main_box = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(main_box)
        main_box.SetMinSize(size)

        # Inner box with the three main view panels in it
        wrap_panels_box = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        wrap_panels_box.SetMinSize(200, 200)
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel3 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        common_flags = wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 5)
        wrap_panels_box.AddMany([(panel1, common_flags),
                                 (panel2, common_flags),
                                 (panel3, common_flags)])

        # Two toolbars for different sets of commands
        toolbar1 = wx.ToolBar(parent=self)
        tool1 = toolbar1.CreateTool(
            toolId=wx.ID_NEW, label='',
            bmpNormal=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_NEW, wx.ART_TOOLBAR))
        toolbar1.AddTool(tool1)
        toolbar1.Realize()

        toolbar2 = wx.ToolBar(parent=self)
        tool2 = toolbar2.CreateTool(
            toolId=wx.ID_SAVE, label='',
            bmpNormal=wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_SAVE, wx.ART_TOOLBAR))
        toolbar2.AddTool(tool2)
        toolbar2.Realize()

        statusbar = wx.StatusBar(parent=self)

        # Add all layout elements
        bar_flags = common_flags.Proportion(0)

        main_box.Add(toolbar1, bar_flags)
        main_box.Add(wrap_panels_box, common_flags.Proportion(1))
        main_box.Add(toolbar2, bar_flags)
        main_box.Add(statusbar, bar_flags)

        self.Layout()

def OnQuit(event):
    exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

All the sub-component generation methods (`_GenerateMenu()`, `_GenerateToolStatusBars()`, and `_GenerateViewPanels()`) work as expected and basically as desired, so I'm leaving them aside.

The various pieces are largely in the right places, but I have a couple quirks here.

#### 1. Status bar expansion

The status bar returned by the `_GenerateToolStatusBars()` method acts like it has `Proportion(1)` set on it: it expands or contracts vertically as the main window is expanded vertically. It also has additional space above it. I can make this stop, however, by setting the panel proportions as follows:

```
bar_flags = common_flags.Proportion(-1)

main_box.Add(toolbar1, bar_flags)
main_box.Add(wrap_panels_box, common_flags.Proportion(0))
main_box.Add(toolbar2, bar_flags)
main_box.Add(statusbar, bar_flags)
```

A `-1` value isn't even documented for the `Proportion()`<sup>[note 2]</sup> setting on a `Sizer`, and the behavior basically matches what I would expect from the original code sample. What's going on here?

#### 2. Later elements in `BoxSizer` sliding over earlier elements

Regardless of how I have the proportions set (at least between the two options above), the latter items behave as expected with relation to each other. They slide over the first element if the box becomes small, however. So, if I have `_GenerateViewPanels()` return the panels (as usual), they slide up and cover the top toolbar. If I make that do nothing (none of the normal panels are generated), the next toolbar slides up and covers the top toolbar. To reiterate: none of the bottom toolbars or panels interact with each other that way; they only do it with the *first* toolbar. As before, I'm confused: what's going on here?

[**Edit:** Made the above code a fully working sample application.]

---

**Notes:**

1. I'm using a wxPython snapshot build of Phoenix, specifically `2.9.5.81-r73784`, running against Python 3.3 on both Windows 7 and OS X. It is *possible* this is a problem from the snapshot build, but I'm doubtful.
2. `Proportion()` is a [fancy wrapper](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.5/classwx_sizer_flags.html#a4b40ff52a93f33e5566491c24ccbd9bd) for the basic `proportion=<value>` argument for adding an element to a Sizer. As for why I tried `-1`, I just mis-remembered the default/base values for the `proportion` argument to `BoxSizer.Add()`.

Comment: post one file please that demonstrates your issue ... just a small file as it stands this question probably will not get an answer, since it requires too much of the answerer ... dont use your fancy Proportion thing just siomething like `self.main_box.Add(whatever, 0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER)`

Comment: If I can replicate it I will, but the majority of a workable file is there already. I didn't see the behavior in trivial examples. As for `Proportion()`, why not use it? It's fully supported by wxWidgets and wxPython.

Comment: I suspect its an issue from adding your sizer_wrapper or something ... unfortunately if you cant replicate it with a simple example this is likely to end up closed as too localized :/

Comment: I have never seen the statusbar do that, but you don't show how you're creating it. As for widgets "sliding" around, that also is hard to see from your example. I am guessing you have parenting issues and will need to use the Widget Inspection Tool to find them. The toolbars shouldn't "slide" at all if they are attached to the frame.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, I think you just saved my sanity; I've been looking for something like the Widget Inspection Tool and somehow had yet to find it. The toolbars are not set as belonging to the Frame, as the documentation *seemed* to imply that only one could be attached at any time. Perhaps that is a misreading of the docs, though?

Comment: I've never had to use multiple toolbars, but this old post talks about one way to do it: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wxPython-Multiple-toolbars-td2277731.html

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I made the code sample a fully-working mini app. Note that I haven't bothered making the panels expand, but the behavior is the same as what I saw in my own app.

Comment: @Mike Driscoll, I will take a look at that sample; thanks. Worst comes to worst, I can just use panels with embedded buttons (or clickable text controls?) with bitmaps associated.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, that link approaches it in almost exactly the same way I am. Nice to know I'm at least generally on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is apparently with the distinct `Proportion()` calls. A little testing and use of the [wxPython Widget Inspection Tool](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.mixins.inspection.html) makes clear that `common_flags` is being modified by the calls on it.

All methods of `SizerFlags` objects return the same object (*not* a copy of the object), so calling a method updates the object and all references to it – it does *not* return a copy, but the same object. So, the original code with comments added explaining what went wrong:

```
common_flags = wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 1)  # creates the object
bar_flags = common_flags.Proportion(0)  # bar_flags points to the common_flags object

# Referencing common_flags with Proportion set to 0
main_box.Add(toolbar1, bar_flags)

# Changes the value of common_flags.
main_box.Add(wrap_panels_box, common_flags.Proportion(1))

# Since bar_flags points to common_flags, it also has Proportion set to 1
main_box.Add(toolbar2, bar_flags)
main_box.Add(statusbar, bar_flags)
```

The solution is simple: declare `bar_flags` and `box_flags` as separate objects. This involves some small repetition of code, but it's worth note that you are *not* repeating the action on the same object; you are performing the same actions on multiple objects. Supplying the following code instead solves the issue:

```
bar_flags = wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 1).Proportion(0)
box_flags = wx.SizerFlags().Expand().Border(wx.ALL, 1).Proportion(1)

main_box.Add(tool_status_bars.main, bar_flags)
main_box.Add(wrap_panels_box, box_flags)
main_box.Add(tool_status_bars.panel_view, bar_flags)
main_box.Add(tool_status_bars.status, bar_flags)
```

As expected, the boxes now relate to each other as they should: the `wrap_panels_box` expands, while the tool and status bars do not.